# Images not showing up with template tags in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to display a user-uploaded image on my HTML template.  I tried a bunch of template tags but none of them seem to be working.  All the settings appear to be configured correctly.  User-uploaded images are correctly uploaded to `project_name/media/`

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'project_name'


# Are the STATIC settings affecting the media settings?  media is for user uploads so I don't think so?

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'project_name/static/',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Things I tried in this HTML:

```
# 'app.profileapp' is not the issue here.  I can access other 'profileapp' attributes just fine (e.g. 'app.profileapp.agent_website' shows up just fine)
<img src = "{{ app.profileapp.agent_picture }}" alt='My image' />
<img src = "{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ app.profileapp.agent_picture }}" alt='My image' />
<img src = "{{MEDIA_ROOT}}{{ app.profileapp.agent_picture }}" alt='My image' />
<img src = "{{ app.profileapp.agent_picture.url }}" alt='My image' />
<img src = "project_folder/{{ agent.agentpremiuminfo.agent_picture }}" alt='My image' />
<img src = "project_folder/media/{{ agent.agentpremiuminfo.agent_picture }}" alt='My image' />
```

Comment: use `.url` like so: `<img src = "{{ app.profileapp.agent_picture.url }}" alt='My image' />`. You can narrow down the problem by inspecting the html `<img>` tag in your browser. Right click -> "Inspect element". Check the attribute for `src` the value should be something like `/media/123/.....jpg`

Comment: @hansTheFranz The inspection tip is very helpful.  I experimented with the tags and tried to land various URLs like `project_name/media/photo.jpg`, `media/photo.jpg`, and even all the way from `C:/.../../project_name/media/photo.jpg`, but it is still displaying the alt text?!?

Comment: I just tried to hardcode it with `../../media/image.jpg` but it is still displaying the alt text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that we have a model `Posts` with an `ImageField` field named `image`. Now in your template (which have access to some `Post` instances) you can display an image with the following:

```
<img src="{{ post.image.url }}"/>
```

where `post` is an instance of `Post`.

I am sure that this should work; I am using it on my website; here is my `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` configurations:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**Important:** Remember to include the following in your `urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # your urls go here
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This will serve user-uploaded media files during development. For more information, look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

Comment: Turns out the `+ static(...)` was the issue.  I added it into my urls.py, but the link I'm on is in another app, and that app's urls.py didn't have the added static().  Added it and now it is working fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is my settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"upload")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/upload/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"assets"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
)

<a href="/static/path/1.jpg"></a>
```